# wget not found in Jupiter notebook to download geojson file from url

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geojson, wget

Im trying to download and read a geojson file from url to use it latter to create a folium map, I already install wget on mac using brew.

when running the code I get this

```
# Download and store a geojson file of Indiana containig AGEB boundaries
import wget
import geojson

!wget https://github.com/Alexrendon/Indianapolis-data/blob/main/Indiana_censustracts.geojson
census_tract = r'Indiana_censustracts.geojson'
print("geojson ready!")
```

OUTPUT

```
zsh:1: command not found: wget
```

Comment: You need to install wget.

Comment: Dunno why you have import wget, its not a python module.... Are you using ZSH in Jupyter by anychance?  what happens if you put `%%bash wget --help` in a jupyter cell. Also can you confirm that you are not on windows.

Comment: `UsageError: %%bash is a cell magic, but the cell body is empty.`       that the result after `%%bash wget --help` im on a Mac

Comment: It might help to show the actual contents of the full .ipynb file in order to give some context to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to use !curl

```
import wget
import geojson

!curl -O https://github.com/Alexrendon/Indianapolis-data/blob/main/Indiana_censustracts.geojson
census_tract = r'Indiana_censustracts.geojson'
print("geojson ready!")
```

Comment: I find it unlikely that using curl is the solution to  wget not working. I can't test this because I'm not on Mac but I'd assume you need to do something along the lines of ```pip install wget``` to get the wget bindings for python.

Comment: @pri0ritize That is a good point. It depends on how you read the question. Is the OP asking "how do I fix this to download this file?" or "how do I fix this to use wget?"

Comment: Totally concur, the question references wget in the title so I assume that was his goal. If his title was how can I download this file  using python I'd have suggested he use curl or requests!

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
# Download and store a geojson file of Indiana containig AGEB boundaries
import wget
import geojson

!wget https://github.com/Alexrendon/Indianapolis-data/blob/main/Indiana_censustracts.geojson
census_tract = r'Indiana_censustracts.geojson'
print("geojson ready!")
```

looks like you are confusing [`wget` python module available at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/wget/) and [GNU Wget command line tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Wget). If you want just to downlad file, neither is required as there exist [`urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) inside `urllib.request` which is part of python standard library. Consider following simple example

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.example.com","example.html")
```

first argument is URL, second is filename

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that you don't have `wget` on your machine. To install it on Mac, just do

```
brew install wget
```

Comment: its already installed, however the solution was to use !curl